# Laplacian in Polar Coordinates - Understanding the derivation

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates, laplacian, chain-rule

I recently saw an exercise to derive the Laplacian for Polar Coordinates by using the chain rule.

$\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (r, \varphi) \mapsto (r\cos{\varphi},r\sin{\varphi}) = (x, y)$

$\psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (x, y) \mapsto (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, arctan\frac{y}{x})= (r,\varphi) = \phi^{-1}$

The exercise reads "Calculate $\Delta (f(\phi(r, \varphi))$ by applying the chain rule to $f(\phi(\psi))$".

This confuses me, since I think $\phi(\psi(x,y))$ isn't doing anything. What am I missing here? How does the $\phi(\psi(x,y))$ help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you are given $f$ in terms of polar coordinates, you are really being given $f \circ \phi$ in the above notation.  So let $F(r, \varphi) = (f \circ \phi)(r,\varphi)$ and apply the chain rule to $f = F \circ \psi$.

Comment: But when I'm given $f$ in terms of polar coordinates, I in fact need to calculate $f \circ \phi$. Why would I want to calculate $\Delta f$ then?

Comment: I think what the question is intending to ask is that, given $f(x,y)$ expressed in polar coordinates, i.e. $f \circ \phi$, what is $\Delta f$ expressed in polar coordinates, i.e. $(\Delta f) \circ \phi$.